What is the relationship between regular singular points and the Cauchy Euler equation?
In my PDE course, my professor shows me how we can take a generic homogenous polynomial coefficient 2nd order differential equation:
$$P(x)y'' + Q(x)y' + R(x)y = 0$$
And transform it into the following expression by diving by $P(x)$ and multiplying by $(x - x_0)$.
$$(x-x_0)^2y'' + [\frac{Q(x)}{P(x)}*(x-x_0)](x-x_0)y' + [\frac{R(x)}{P(x)}*(x-x_0)^2]y = 0  $$
Then, we are told that if $x_0$ is a singular point and:

$[\frac{Q(x)}{P(x)}*(x-x_0)]$
$[\frac{R(x)}{P(x)}*(x-x_0)^2]$

are analytic at $x_0$, then the singularity at $x_0$ is regular, while otherwise the singularity at $x_0$ is irregular.
I'm not sure what is going on here. I know the new equation form resembles that of a Cauchy-Euler equation - with (1) and (2) above corresponding to the coefficients $b$ and $c$ of the Cauchy-Euler equation:
$$a(x-x_0)^2y'' + b(x-x_0)y' + cy$$
but I'm not sure what kind of meaningful connection there is between this correspondence and how (1) and (2) being analytic necessarily implies that $x_0$ is a regular singular point.

It rests simply on the fact, that for an analytic function the operator $$((z-z_0))\partial_z))^k$$ removes the the constant and changes the power series $$\sum a_n (z-z_0)^n $$ by a factor $k$ only. So its possible to factor out the series from the equation.
